# Method to check all points within a closed path

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, geometry, computational-geometry

I have 4 or more points that make up a closed path. I want to get each point in the image within the closed path. If there any method to do something like this?

Comment: What is an image in your case? Discrete rectangular grid of points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 - (BOOL)isPointContain:(NSArray *)vertices point:(CGPoint)test {
    NSUInteger nvert = [vertices count];
    NSInteger i, j, c = 0;
    CGPoint verti, vertj;

    for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
        verti = [(NSValue *)[vertices objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        vertj = [(NSValue *)[vertices objectAtIndex:j] CGPointValue];
        if (( (verti.y > test.y) != (vertj.y > test.y) ) &&
        ( test.x < ( vertj.x - verti.x ) * ( test.y - verti.y ) / ( vertj.y - verti.y ) + verti.x) )
            c = !c;
    }

    return (c ? YES : NO);
}


NSArray *Vertices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(10, 40)],
                            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(30, 48)],
                            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(50, 80)],
                            [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(45, 100)],

                            nil
                            ];

CGPoint point = CGPointMake(30, 28);
if ([self isPointContain:Vertices point:point]) {
    NSLog(@"YES");
} else {
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

Comment: What if it's not a rectangle? or when it has more than 4 vertices?

Comment: @KhawarAli check with mulitiple vertices

Answer (score 0):

It's a large area in *Computer Graphics* and *Image Processing* with many applications in *Geographical Informational Systems*. Look for "Polygon-Clipping Algorithms" or try another StackExchange site:

http://gis.stackexchange.com